# How to copy distinct date from one column in a database to another column in another database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new to SQL and i want to copy `distinct dates` from a column named `starttime`  in a table `user` in a database `MyDb`,  to a column `playing_date` in a table `collection` in another database named `viral.`
I have used the following query but its not working:

```
mysqli_select_db($con,'MyDb');
 $query1  = "INSERT INTO viral.collection.playing_date SELECT DISTICT date(starttime) FROM user";
 if(mysqli_query($con,$query1))
  echo "Successfully Inserted";
 else
  echo "error";
```

How should i correct it?

Comment: not working **HOW**? if it's due to a query  error, then simply dumping out `error` is worse than useless. At minimum you should be doing `echo mysqli_error($con)` so you can see EXACTLY what the db's trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the N in DISTINCT

```sql
INSERT INTO viral.collection.playing_date SELECT DISTINCT date(starttime) FROM user
```

Comment: Maybe if you put the playing_date as a value:

    INSERT INTO viral.collection (playing_date) SELECT DISTINTCT date(starttime) FROM user

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTICT date(starttime) into viral.collection.playing_date FROM user;
```

this will work!

Comment: use this after

 USE MyDb;